# jQuery параметры плагина

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте!
Возникла проблема с плагином jQuery (самописка). Параметры, которые я записываю в переменную плагина при каждой новой инициализации перекрываются более новыми. В параметрах я храню селекторы для элементов.
В моем случае, постоянно перезаписывается объект data (я имею несколько .fixed-block на странице).
Сам вопрос: могу ли я хранить параметры для каждой отдельной инициализации плагина? Мне необходимо сохранять параметры для каждого проинициализированного блока.

```js
(function($){
    jQuery.fn.fixedBlock = function(options){
        $.extend({

        },options);

        var data = {
            fixed: false,
            original: null,
            copy: null
        };

        var init = function(){
            //
        };

        var check = function() {
            //
        };

        var copyElement = function(jQueryElement) {
            //
        };

        var calcTopValue = function() {
            //
        };

        return this.each(init);
    }
}(jQuery));

$('.fixed-block').fixedBlock();
```

Answer (score 1):

судя по коду  параметры никуда не сохраняются, потому что extend объединяет все в целевой объект, а он у тебя даже не определен , соответственно, так как он у тебя нигде не определен, то он и превращается в мусор.

По поводу `$.extend`:
Если задать два или более объекта, то результатом будет их объединение. В случае, если вы зададите только один объект, функция extend() добавит его содержимое в глобальный объект $ (jQuery). Таким образом можно расширять возможности библиотеки, добавляя свои функции в ее пространство имен. Это может быть полезно при написании плагинов.

Напомним, что в результате объединения объектов, первый из них будет изменен (он же будет возвращен в качестве результата выполнения функции extend()). Если нужно, чтобы ни один из заданных объектов не был изменен, то можно задать в качестве параметра target пустой объект:

```
var object = $.extend({}, object1, object2);
```

Eсли сохранять все аргументы в сам объект jquery, то он быстро превратится в мусорку данных, и потом дебажить код будет почти невозможно.

Comment: это просто пример кода. сам код плагина достаточно большой. 
я написал несколько плагинов опираясь на то, что он будет сохранять параметры для каждого проинициализированного селектора. плагин создает dom-копию элемента и сохраняет её в переменную. после каждой инициализации эти параметры перекрываются более новыми и мне интересно было бы узнать, куда можно сохранять эти самые параметры таким образом, чтобы они не перезаписывались при каждой новой инициализации

Answer (score 0):

Собственно, решил свою проблему, немного переписав плагин. Параметры проинициализированного элемента можно сохранять в дата-параметры. Пример кода:

```
(function($){
    var methods = {
        init : function (options) {
            options = $.extend({
                fixedClass: 'fixed-top',
                invisibleClass: 'invisible',
                copyClass: 'copy'
            }, options);

            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this),
                    data = $this.data('fixedBlock'); 

                if (!data) {
                    $this.data('fixedBlock',{
                        original: $this,
                        copy: copy($this)
                    }); // Здесь я сохраняю нужные мне данные в дата-параметр "fixedBlock"

                }
            });
        },

        destroy : function () {

        }
    };

    $.fn.fixedBlock = function (method) {
        if ( methods[method] ) {
            return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
        } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
            return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
        } else {
            $.error('Метод с именем ' + method + ' не существует для jQuery.fixedBlock');
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```